# DataLayerException in a API call

Tags: exception, facebook-graph-api

In my logs I have one Facebook API exception and I don't find any information about it. Anybody knows this?

The Exception is:

```
[error] => Array
                (
                    [message] => Unable to get 'r' connection to tier cdb.dfs
                    [type] => DataLayerException
                )
```